# How would I measure this battery circuit with a multimeter?

Tags: electrical-engineering, measurements, circuits, battery

[image: Image of circuit]

The wire is attached to the bottom of each D battery.
I already know that I have to put the bottom of the light bulb on the positive side of the battery.

My multimeter looks like this:
[image: Multimeter]

I'm not sure where to put the testing probes. I don't think this is important, but the wire is made of steel wool.

I hope I can get some help.

Comment: What are you trying to measure. Voltage, or current draw?

Comment: vtc as unclear and not an engineering question

Comment: @agentp what is vtc unclear

Comment: vote to close, which should be understood as a prompt to the poster to clarify the question.

Comment: why did I try to downvote my own post lol

Comment: I suggest that you clarify if your trying to measure voltage or current. The way to measure current is different from the way you measure voltage.

Answer (score 2):

If you trying to measure voltage, connect the black connector probe (Terminal) to COM. Move the rotatory switch 20 DCV. The dot should point to 20 DCV. Then place the black exposed probe to negative and red expose probe to positive button on the battery. You should read somewhere around 1.5V for the D size battery.

[image]

Checkout some of the links below. This should help you with your questions.

Reference:

- [How to Use a Multimeter?](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/how-to-use-a-multimeter/measuring-voltage)
- [How to Use a Multimeter: Measuring Voltage](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GZX3MyBkMvA)